# Meaning of 'Chasing the sinking sun'?

Tags: meaning

There is this phrase that comes up in song lyrics every now and then. It has some kind of romantic flavour to it, but I don't know it's meaning: 'Chasing the Sinking Sun'

Shout Out Louds - Chasing the Sinking Sun @ Youtube: (https://youtu.be/k3puu5yKw_g)

Comment: The sinking sun refers to the sun that seem to "sink" into the ocean at Sunset (if you're looking west). Someone whose capacity of reflexion is disminished by strong feeling, could try to follow (chase) it in order to catch it. In short it means trying to do something impossible while your judgement is clouded by strong feelings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is requesting an interpretation of song lyrics, which will be a matter of opinion. Even the basic metaphor here can have multiple meanings, from hurrying to complete something before an immovable deadline to participating in an unwinnable race.

Comment: @choster I'd vote to close as off topic but because it is just supposed to be metaphorical (solution: understand the dictionary meanings of the words first, then try to put it in context metaphorically.. wait... that _is_ the problem with lyrics and poetry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally used in Pink Floyd's Time

> [You run and you run to catch up with the sun but its sinking](http://genius.com/3013321/Pink-floyd-time/And-you-run-and-you-run-to-catch-up-with-the-sun-but-its-sinking-racing-around-to-come-up-behind-you-again-the-sun-is-the-same-in-a-relative-way-but-youre-older-shorter-of-breath-and-one-day-closer-to-death)
>
> Once you realize you’ve wasted all this time, you anxiously try to catch up to the time lost and do something with your life

Answer (score 1):

It's a wistful metaphor for the forlorn hope (it's impossible to catch the sun under normal circumstances) of recapturing past glories (the sun at noon).

Answer (score 0):

Travel in an ever-westerly direction. The implication of 'chasing' is that the travel is ongoing.